# c# receive data from GPS over TCP connection

Tags: c#, tcp, gps, gprs

I put a GPS Tracing device in my car, which sends me position information every ten seconds. 
Now I want to develop an application that will show information about position of my car.

The problem is that I don't know how to receive data from GPS over GPRS/TCP connection.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you implement this? I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can develop a C# application which acts as a server and your GPS device equipped with GSM/GPRS modem will connect to your server. Once the connection is established, you can receive and transmit data from/to GPS device.

Your server PC should be on public/static IP.